# WCF - WebHttpBinding - RESTful - Performance Issue

Tags: performance, wcf, rest, webhttpbinding

first time poster so go easy on me.

I am currently trying to address a performance issue when hitting my web service after a one minute period of inactivity. Literally after one minute of THAT user not hitting the web service then the next call will take 15 seconds before actually hitting the service operation. If you keep making random (not the same service operation just so you guys don't think it is "caching" the call) service operation calls the service returns immediately (less than a second).

Here are some "timings" I decided to take so you can see how I came to the one minute of inactivity:

1. 2:04PM
2. 2:16PM --15 seconds
3. 2:21PM --15 seconds
4. 2:24PM --15 seconds
5. 2:25PM --15 seconds

Again, if you hit the web service continuously without a one minute period of inactivity then ALL methods will return in less than a second.

Here are some details regarding my web service:

1. WCF, WebHttpBinding, RESTful, using HTTPs.
2. Basic Authentication + Custom Authentication using IDispatchMessageInspector. Authentication happens with EVERY call (except to the Initializer.aspx page).
3. Custom Initialization.aspx page has been created which is called every night after the Application Pool is recycled. This page caches a bunch of global data used by all users along with starting that compile.
4. Application Pool ONLY recycles every night at 2AM. Worker threads are never killed off because timeout is disabled.

I heard about ReliableSession but as the setting implies that sounds like it would only work for PerSession, not PerCall.

Is there any way to resolve this or am I stuck to resorting to "pinging" the server every 45 seconds using a dummy service operation?

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue. We have multiple domain controllers. When the user was getting authenticated it would start from the forest level and work its way down to the actual domain controller that server resided on. The firewalls that were put in place were blocking all domain controllers except what the server resided on.

So basically, it would fail to communicate to the N+ domain controllers until it finally reached the only one it could.

You can fix this a number of ways but we just created firewall rules to allow the web server to communicate to the domain controller the users needed to be authenticated against.